# LoadCursorFromFile returns NULL. GetLastError also 0

Tags: c++, windows, cursor

I'm trying to load cursor with

```
LoadCursorFromFile()
```

function from WinAPI and have faced such misterious problem: after about 2 hrs playing my game (I'm changing cursor in game) it fails to load the same resourse, which have been loaded many times already (and cursor simply disappear).

Also after

```
tCursor = LoadCursorFromFile(filename);
DWORD lusterr = GetLastError();
```

lusterr is 0; File path for LoadCursorFromFile is like "assets/images/cursors/static.cur".

If it is needed I will share this cursor. But again: it has been loaded many times already and worked fine.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why it all happend?

Comment: I wonder if you're running out of GDI resources or some such...

Comment: Please format your post properly. Five months is more than sufficient time in which to learn how to do that.

Comment: @NPE Could you plz tell me how can I control it? Right now I'm debugging it and trying to do something.

Comment: @ElDorado: Put simply, make sure you're not leaking any resources.

Comment: @NPE You were right! After LoadCursorFromFile every time I must have use DestroyCursor before reload cursor

Comment: I think you can use the taskmanager (Control-Shift-Escape) to view the GDI resources for each process, although you will have to configure the columns shown appropriately. Since you're using C++, consider creating an RAII wrapper class that takes care of proper allocation/deallocation. For small things like cursors that don't change, I would also consider loading them once on startup and then using them without reloading each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a GDI resource leak. Make sure you free whatever resources you acquire (cursors etc).

Comment: Exactly! I've forgotten about DestroyCursor everytime I reload it